# MySQL GROUP BY subject

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table called 'teachers'.
teachers table has the following fields

- id
- schoolnumber
- gender
- firstname
- lastname
- subjectgroup
- status
- time

I would like to display all the teachers based on their subject (subjectgroup).

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE status = '1' GROUP BY subjectgroup
```

It is grouping the teachers correctly but it's only showing 1 teacher per subject.

Output:

- Science:

  - Mr. ScienceMan
- English:

  - Mrs. English
- Math:

  - Mr. Math

but i want is the listing of teachers by subject

There should be more than one teacher in the groups.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`Group by` will group those rows into one row. It sounds like you want to `order by` subject instead

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer.  Yeah, order by did work however is outputting the following: Science(title) -> Mr. ScienceMan1 Science(title repeated again) Mr. ScienceMan2 etc..  Is it possible to output each subject title once?

Comment: This is where you'd use your programming to filter out that data when you're displaying it - if the subject matches the same as the one in the last row, don't echo it out to the screen

Comment: Remember that sql is for getting/inserting/updating etc, PHP (Or other languages) are for the manipulation of that data on the screen. As you loop through your rows, you can then play around with the data you have.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're doing, you want ORDER BY, which sorts by the given field.

GROUP BY is for times when you're trying to get summary data, as when you've got a SUM() or AVERAGE() or maybe a COUNT() in the SELECT statement. It tells SQL how to break up which items to put together for those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subjectgroup, GROUP_CONCAT(firstname SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM teachers
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY subjectgroup;
```

[Group concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is the function you need in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This will bring a list of the teacher names separated by commas:

```
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            DISTINCT (
                CONCAT_WS(' ', `firstname`, `lastname`)
            ) SEPARATOR ', '
        ) AS `teacher_list`,
        `subjectgroup`
    FROM
        `teachers`
    WHERE
        `status` = 'i'
    GROUP BY
        `subjectgroup`
```